# Simultaneous Diagonalisation

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Im stuck at this problem

Find an invertible Real Matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{-1}BP$ are both diagonal where $A$ and $B$ are real matrices.

a)   $A=\begin{bmatrix}  
1&2\\
0&2\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$B=\begin{bmatrix}
3&-8\\
0&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

b) $A=\begin{bmatrix}  
1&1\\
1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$   and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&a\\
a&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I know that diagonalisable commuting matrices can be simultaneously diagonalised but I'm not able to proceed.Kindly help.

Comment: Could you find common eigenvectors of $A, B$?

Comment: Dietrich Burde Hi I did see that in both a and b cases the matrices commute

Comment: Thank you xbh I was able to find common Eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$ ,thereby it becomes easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the first pair of matrices, it turns out that the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$ are eigenvectors of each of them. Therefore, take$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$Can you solve the other problem now?

Comment: Thank you very much I was able to do the other problem also